# How to lock the UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, locking

I'm looking for a way to lock the user interface, for example when I select "Lock" from the options menu, the UI will be block from touches. It's sort of adding an overlay with some kind of lock icon over the UI.
Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to do that on multiple activities or just one ?
If it's just one, then add a transparent ViewGroup(MatchParent,Parent) to the top of your view hierarchy. Make it Gone by default.
Then in OnCreate(), add a OnTouchListener that always returns true (meaning that it took into account the touch);
Then when you need it, just make it "Visible".

Explanation : adding it to the top will make it the top-most "layer" in the view hierarchy. So it will be first to receive touch events which you then veto by returning true to the listener's caller.

Comment: Thanks, your idea works great! It's just that I can't make the top-most ViewGroup transparent so that the views below it are still visible. Or am I doing anything wrong? Could you give me the XML layout or some code?

Comment: Can you share what your issue was ? Someone else might run into it one day.

Answer (score 4):

To make the entire window of the activity untouchable, call this:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

to make it touchable again, call

```
this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Though this may cause an ANR...if you can get around that then this is the easiest method, otherwise what bitbox said may be the apropriate solution

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but because of the ANR I'm using bitbox's solution.